# If checkbox is checked include variable

Tags: javascript

I have a long list in my dataString, here is a small portion:

```
var dataString = '&header' + header
               + '&logo' + logo
               + '&body' + body;
```

I would like to include logo in the dataString only if the logo checkbox is checked.
How do I check for logo checkbox is checked inside the dataString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might I recommend the ternary operator?

```
var logoCheckboxIsChecked = document.getElementById('logoCheckboxId').checked;
var dataString = '&header' + header
               + logoCheckboxIsChecked ? '&logo' + logo : '',
               + '&body' + body;
```

**UPDATE**

In my initial answer, `logoCheckboxIsChecked` is simply a variable that holds the `checked` state of the checkbox. I could have also written it as follows:

```
var logoCheckbox = document.getElementById('logoCheckboxId');
var logoCheckboxIsChecked = logoCheckbox.checked;
```

In answer to your other question ("does an isChecked function exist in Javascript"):

There is no `isChecked` function in JavaScript (to my knowledge), but you can make one if you like. Here is a simple example of an `isChecked` function:

```
// simplified example
var isChecked = function isChecked(elem) {
    var checked = false;
    if (elem.checked !== undefined)
        checked = elem.checked;
    }
    return checked;
};
```

Example of usage:

```
var dataString = '&header' + header
               + isChecked(document.getElementById('logoCheckboxId')) ? '&logo' + logo : '',
               + '&body' + body;
```

Comment: Could you clarify `logoCheckboxIsChecked` does an isChecked function exist in Javascript?

Comment: There is no `isChecked` function in JavaScript (to my knowledge), but you can make one if you like (see updated answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
var dataString = '&header' + header;

if (document.getElementById('id_of_logo_checkbox').checked)
{
    dataString += '&logo' + logo;
}

dataString += '&body' + body;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataString = "...";
if(document.getElementById('checkid').checked = true;
{
dataString += logo;
}
//...code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById('checkid').checked == true)
dataString += logo;
```

Comment: that is my exact answer. in every detail except for the curly brackets

Comment: Which one is exact answer for u